# Understanding memory usage of neural network

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to understand how the convnet memory usage calculation shown [here](http://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/#case) was performed (scroll down to the *VGGNet in detail* section).

The output of the calculation to see how much memory the VGGNet network uses says:

```
TOTAL memory: 24M * 4 bytes ~= 93MB
```

however adding up all the `memory:` values from each of the layers in the list only gives about 15M * 4 bytes and I'm not sure where the rest of the memory in this total came from.

Comment: I would say that this is inconsistent example.

Comment: I get ~90MB using the same math on 19-layer implementation E, instead of 16 layer D: http://arxiv.org/pdf/1409.1556.pdf

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add memory for the FCs:

> FC: [1x1x4096]  memory:  4096  weights: 7*7*512*4096 = 102,760,448
>
> FC: [1x1x4096]  memory:  4096  weights: 4096*4096 = 16,777,216
>
> FC: [1x1x1000]  memory:  1000 weights: 4096*1000 = 4,096,000

I think that's the lost 9M in your calculations.

Comment: Where do you think the missing 9M is in those figures, are you adding up 4096+4096+1000? Those figures describe the number of neurons in each layer, the calculation assumes each neuron takes 4 bytes of memory (that's why the final figure is multiplied by 4 bytes) so they don't account for the difference